# Optimize glm::translate

Tags: c++11, glm-math

We use glm::translate frequently, and the usage is generally like

```
glm::mat4 m;
m = glm::translate(m, glm::vec3( x, y, z ));
```

It looks like there is a copy involved, translate returns a matrix by value that is copied into the original matrix. is there a glm::translate version that transforms the mat4 in-place or uses c++11 move semantics?

Comment: Is the question still actual?

Comment: yes, definitely

Comment: Then another question: Is `m` always supposed to be an identity matrix?

Comment: Also, move semantics won't help you here, since no internal storage to move.

Comment: no, m is referenced from the top a stack and then altered:

`auto& ms_top = ms.top();
ms_top = glm::translate(ms_top, glm::vec3( x, y, z ));`